# Calcular campo en Models que dependen de otros models, es viable?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Quiero rellenar un field en un modelo de Django (Establecimiento) el campo es promedio_calificaciones, donde mi idea es por cada review de un usuario tomar ese dato de otro modelo y sumarlo y guardarlo en Establecimiento, pero no estoy seguro como manejarlo.

```
class Establecimiento(models.Model):
    """ Establecimientos para Visitar y Calificar """

    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    descripcion = models.TextField()
    promedio_calificaciones = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(10)])
    establecimiento_categoria = models.IntegerField(choices=EDIFICIOS)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    # @property
    # def calcular_calificacion(self, id):
    """ Podria introducir mi Logica aqui """ ?
    """"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""


    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

class Review(models.Model):
    review_titulo = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    review_opinion = models.TextField()
    calificacion = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(10)])
    establecimiento = models.ForeignKey(
        'Establecimiento', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    persona = models.ForeignKey('Persona', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Review(#{}) de "{}" por {}'.format(self.id, self.establecimiento.nombre, self.persona.nombre, self.persona.apellido)
```

Answer (score 0):

En vez de llamar al nombre "calcular_calificacion" llámala "save" para poder sobreescribir en la función final la cual es la que salva tus modelos en la base de datos. Luego hereda de la función save padre para que haga su función original, que es la propiamente dicha, salvar estos modelos en la base de datos.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # Lo que quieras calcular y que funcione como setter
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```